# need to access a manytomanyfield in django templates

Tags: python, django

So i have these models:

```
class CofifiUser(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class QuoteIdea(models.Model):
  creator = models.ForeignKey(CofifiUser,related_name="creator")
  text = models.TextField(max_length=250)
  votes = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="0")
  votes_received = models.ManyToManyField(CofifiUser)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And i want:

```
If request.user.username is in the item.votes_received.all 
  <button class="disabled">Button</button>
Else 
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
```

Is almost the same thing as the Like Button on Facebook .
You cannot give more than one like to a page ( in python/django )
Please need some help here :)

Comment: Why don't you do condition in view, and just use a boolean in template?

Comment: is about a social network .. and i have to display more QuoteIdea on a single page, posted from different users .. is almost imposible to make this with the view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that's important to keep in mind here is the performance implication of having to query a many-to-many relationship for each comparison, or even pre-loading all of the m2m data to see if the user is in the `votes_received` queryset.

In a case like this, I usually opt for a de-normalized way to do the boolean comparison. I will create a field to just hold the IDs as [comma-separated ints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) and update the field via a [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save).

This greatly simplifies things at the view and template level and also avoids having to do any joins, or any additional queries at all.

Assuming you're looping over a list of `QuoteIdea` instances and passing an instance of `CofifiUser` to the template, and you have added a field to `QuoteIdea` called something like `cofifi_vote_ids` you can do:

```
{# returns added to prevent wrapping #}

{% for quote_idea in quote_ideas %}
    <button class="btn 
        {% if cofifi_user.id in quote_idea.cofifi_vote_ids %}
        disabled
        {% else %}
        btn-primary
        {% endif %}">Button</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help. Upvotes and accepted answers appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked very good.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs 
{% for creator in item.votes_received.all %}
  {%if user.id == creator.id %}
    disabled
  {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
">Send Coffee</button>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this results in a SQL statement being executed unless you use `prefetch_related` on the `item` instance.